# Use of the jsfiddle tag

Tags: discussion, tags, jsfiddle

Should the jsfiddle tag be used when a post just uses jsfiddle to demonstrate code, or should the jsfiddle tag only be used when the question is about jsfiddle?

I think it should not be used just because there is a code example on jsfiddle, but the question should be about jsfiddle in order for the tag to be used.

Either way, I think the jsfiddle tag wiki should be updated to make it clear when the tag should be used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tag should be used when the question is *about* jsfiddle.

Tags are about adding value to the question - allowing one to see quickly what subjects the question is about. If jsfiddle is only there to illustrate the question, it shouldn't be tagged with it.

---

Update:

I have added a clarification to the tag wiki, explaining it should be used when the question is *about* jsFiddle.

Comment: Very true. A nice blog post about meta tags: [The Death of Meta Tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/).

Comment: I'm confused though. What kind of question could I really ask that would be *about* jsFiddle in the sense of programming? It's a very plug-n-play kind of site that doesn't really require any support that SO could provide, and the tag seems to be used purely meta-like.

Comment: @animuson, you're right, so don't use the jsFiddle tag :)