# What is the best way to handle a lot of misused tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, review

So today I noticed a question that had the [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) tag. As the question was not about JSFiddle, and only included a link to the site, I thought somebody has just created this for the sake of it. So I decided the best action would be to remove it, and try to stop it from getting out of control.

But then I searched (clicked the tag) for other questions that used it and I was amayonaised to see over 500 questions had the very same tag! Most of which were incorrectly tagged. So I cleaned up a couple and then quickly got bored.

So I am wondering, aside from going through them all by myself, is there a more efficient way?

I think it would be a great idea if there was some feature (probably an admin feature) that allowed a new tag queue to be added to the review list. I think this could work well as follows:

1. Somebody brings up the problematic tag in question (e.g. Me on here)
2. An admin reviews my concern, and decides that the tag is very misused
3. That admin adds the tag for review in a (temporary) new review queue.
4. All users that can review can then go through existing tags, and vote for "No action" or "Remove tag"
5. The world becomes a slightly better place

...or not?

---

By the way, I tried to add some new tags to this post but I don't have the rep. So if someone could create them for me that would be swell: "musefan", "today", "sunny-spells", "pointless-tags"

Comment: Have a look at [meta-tag:clean-up] and perhaps post a "Call to Arms".

Comment: I'm **amayonaised**, too. It seems that there is no way to **ketchup** with all these bad tags that just don't cut the **mustard**. That's why we **relish** the Meta users who spend so much time cleaning them up.

Comment: Something with **salsa** ...

Comment: Related: [Clean up. Is \[jsfiddle\] tag useful?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136052/clean-up-is-jsfiddle-tag-useful) and [Use of the jsfiddle tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116407/use-of-the-jsfiddle-tag)

Comment: If you added more guidance for users this might help stop the problem at the sauce.

Answer (score 3):

*Nec Hercules contra plures*, but you can increase your chances:

1. By using individual weapons, such as [Burninator toolkit](https://stackapps.com/questions/4207/burninator-toolkit)
2. By calling guerillas, this is what tag [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) is for
3. If you are devout, you can call for divine interventions - admins are rumoured to have tools to burn the whole tags alive

Comment: musefan does have the reputation required to use the toolkit (10k+), but you might want to add for future folks that the toolkit only works for 10k+ folks.

Comment: Actually, with my fix, it requires only the priviledges to edit questions, and musefan has 15k repo on SO.

Comment: Oh, awesomesauce!

Comment: I stopped at Hercules